# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when dismissing modalViewController iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, exc-bad-access, modalviewcontroller

I've been scratching my head for a long time now, trying to solve this problem. I've searched StackOverflow, and have found people asking for something that resembles my problem like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662550/upgraded-to-xcode-4-2-now-exc-bad-access-on-dimissmodalviewcontroller) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173517/using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-to-send-a-mail-get-exc-bad-access-when-dism), but none of the answers given have helped me.

To explain the problem in detail:

1. I've used Apple's Paging example to enable paging between view controllers
2. The View hierachy is as follows: UIWindow -> UIScrollView (MainController) -> UIViewControllers.

   I use this code to create a delegate to the Viewcontroller containing the UISCrollview:

   ```
   if(page == 0)
   {
       ContractsViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

       if ((NSNull *) controller == [NSNull null])
       {
           controller = [[ContractsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContractsView" bundle:nil];
           controller.delegate = self;
           [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
           [controller release];
       }

       // add the controller's view to the scroll view
       if (controller.view.superview == nil)
       {
           CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
           frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
           frame.origin.y = 0;
           controller.view.frame = frame;
           controller.view.tag = 0;
           [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

       }
   }
   ```

The problem then occurs, when I try to present a modalviewcontroller from my ViewController inside the scrollview using the delegate. It works a few times, but then gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've also tried posting a notification, and creating a listener in the MainController, to present it that way, but still the same problem.

When testing in iOS 4.3 everything works like a charm, but in iOS5 I get the issue.

I hope someone can help me get rid of this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried to set Zombie detection in Xcode ? Your problem could be related to memory deallocation, just a guess you are trying to send a message to a deallocated delegate.

Comment: Yes I have, but NSZombie doesn't give me any feedback

Comment: how do you get viewControllers ? Did you put some breakpoint ? At what line are you getting bad_access ? How do you call the modal view ?

Comment: 1. I add the viewcontrollers as a subview of my Scrollview. 2. It's a MFMailComposer i'm calling, so I've only tried putting breakpoints in my own code. 3. I'm getting a bad access at [delegate dismissModalViewController:]. 4. I call it like this: [delegate presentModalViewController:].

Comment: well, it's hard to say, but why don't you call just 'self' instead of [delegate dismiss...] and [delegate present...] ? It is the main controller which is showing the modal. Also, you are releasing controller, and that should also release it's delegate.

Comment: The reason why I'm not using self to present the modalView, is because I want to present the MailComposer. I can get the MailComposer to appear, but if I press cancel, the screen will fade black. It's because it's trying to show a second modalView, that has 3 buttons: Delete Draft, Save Draft or Cancel, but for some reason I can't see it. If I use the delegate, I get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start thank you for all your answers! I've finally found the solution to the problem.

As mentioned in my question, I used Apple's [Pagecontrol sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) as a template for my project. This template has a rootViewController which has an XIB with a window containing an UIScrollview and a Pagecontrol.

The problem happened, when I was trying to present the ModalView from a UIViewController inside the scrollview. I wanted to use the delegate, to present it through the rootViewController, but found out that it was using the UIScrollview to present it.

The UIScrollView object was apperently not retained, so after a couple of dismisses I hit the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I then figured, that i needed an UIView in the rootViewController, and placed it in the bottom viewhierachy in the XIB, and connected it with the view of the rootViewController. After I did that, I could use [delegate present..] and [delegate dismiss..] in the UIViewController without the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Yay! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem.. in the first if you release `controller` object and then you try to use it in the second if loop because of which you recieve this. release the controller object after both the if loops have passed.

**EDIT**:

try this code instead..

```
if(page == 0)
{
    ContractsViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *) controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        controller = [[[ContractsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContractsView" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        controller.view.tag = 0;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately. I could display the ModalViewController the first time, but I recieved a "message sent to deallocated instance 0x8c9ee90", when I tried to present it again.

I've also tried retaining the viewcontroller in my MainController headerfile, but the problem stays the same.

Comment: I can see that sveinungkb suggested the same. I just tried it, and it seemed to work. I can present and dismiss the modalviewcontroller 10+ times, but then it gives me the EXC_BAD_ACCESS again. In the modalviewcontroller, where I present it, I've triede using [self.delegate presentModalViewController:] and [_delegate presentModalViewController:] but it didn't help

Comment: The code as written would leak if there wasn't a bug elsewhere.

Comment: @JeremyP Could you be more specific? When I use instruments, I get some weird leaks: Malloc 48 Bytes, libsystem_c.dylib, strdup. When I double click it show my main with a 100% leak.

Comment: @Krueger: The controller object in your original code is correctly released.  If there is a memory management issue, it is not in the fragment you published.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing your `[controller release];` and adding an autorelease: `controller = [[[ContractsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContractsView" bundle:nil] autorelease];`
You don't own `controller` when it's returned from `objectAtIndex:`, so that way you could have the same behavior for both controllers, no releases.

Comment: See my comment to Ankit Srivastava's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code with NSZombiesEnabled.

My guess is that the viewControllers object is either never initialised or is being released prematurely.

Also, there's this `if (page == 0)` wierdness:

```
if(page == 0) // <== only the first page ever gets the init code calling
{
    ContractsViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *) controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        // ** SNIP **

        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page   // <<=== always 0
                                   withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    // ** SNIP **

}
```

Comment: I've already tried that. But I'm not getting any feedback. I just get the plain old EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I've also used instruments, but when I hit the EXC_BAD_ACESS instruments stops, and I don't get any stack-trace.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line that says `[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];` and make sure viewControllers is not nil.

Comment: I just checked. It's not nil but contains objects as it should.

Comment: Is it correct that you only execute any of this code when `pages == 0`?

Comment: I have 4 pages, but yes each page only get initialized once.

Comment: @Krueger Your initialisation code is inside an if that says `if (page == 0)` which means only page 0 ever gets a controller.  Everything else stays as NSNull

Comment: I have an if(page == x) for every viewController, so they all get initialized. If they weren't initialized, I wouldn't be able to see them at all.

Comment: @Krueger: OK, last idea, run in the debugger with breakpoints set for-C exceptions.  When the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occutrs look down the stack for the frame in which you present the controller and then po the object it is trying to present.

Comment: I haven't tried what you're suggesting before, so bare with me. I added a breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator, chose Exception: C++ named std::bad_exception, Break: On Throw and Action: Debugger Command: Po. But I don't see any difference in feedback. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Krueger: It's not a C++ exception.  Try settign abreakoint for all exception on throw.

Comment: Like this: http://media3.playstadium.dk/img/sl/blandet/exceptionXcode.png? - > Because that didn't give me anything either.

Comment: @Krueger: that should work.  Have you got breakopoints enabled?

Comment: Yes, but I still only get: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x90). Nothing in the lldb debugger.

Comment: @Krueger Try the gdb - lldb is still quite flakey